# How to send audio output to Apple TV?

Tags: objective-c, avaudiosession, airplay, apple-tv

I want to add a button to send the audio output to the Applle TV. I use below code but it does not work. Can you help what I am doing wrong?

First I change the AVAudioSession category to be AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient (for searching the connected bluetooth devices for iOS 7 and 8, I have to do this.)

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&err];
```

Then I use this method for switching audio to Apple TV

```
- (BOOL)switchAirPlay:(BOOL)onOrOff
{
    NSError* audioError = nil;
    BOOL changeResult = NO;
    if (onOrOff) {
        self.bipAudioSessionManagerDeviceCurrent = Device_AppleTV;

        AVAudioSessionPortDescription* airplayPort = [self airplayAudioDevice];
        changeResult = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:airplayPort error:&audioError];
    } else {
        AVAudioSessionPortDescription* airplayPort = [self airplayAudioDevice];
        changeResult = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:airplayPort error:&audioError];
    }

    if (audioError) {
        DDLogError(@"Apple TV error, audioSession: %@ %zd %@", [audioError domain], [audioError code], [[audioError userInfo] description]);
    }

    if (!changeResult) {
        DDLogError(@"Apple TV error, audioSession: %@ %zd %@", [audioError domain], [audioError code], [[audioError userInfo] description]);
    }

    return changeResult;
}

- (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)airplayAudioDevice {
    NSArray* builtinRoutes = @[AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay];
    return [self audioDeviceFromTypes:builtinRoutes];
}

- (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)audioDeviceFromTypes:(NSArray*)types {
    NSArray* routes = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* route in routes) {
        if ([types containsObject:route.portType]) {
            return route;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Edit 1:** 
According to the documentation in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html the AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient category supports AirPlay.

**Edit 2:**

```
NSArray *inputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

Size of the inputs is 1 although iphone is connected to he Apple TV. I don't understand why size is not equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You send your audio by using AirPlay please visit this link
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/

Comment: Thanks but I need an advice for my code, it handles bluetooth, earPeace, iphone, iphone speaker but why not air play.